# Most efficient way to loop through multiple mysql result rows

Tags: php, mysql

I understand this is probably a mundane question for most, although I've been hard pressed to find an example i can learn from.. I have this function to retrieve some owner details. In some cases it will retrieve two contacts. I want to have the second set of details saved in the array as $output['owner_id1']... etc, just not certain on how to accomplish.

```
 function retrieve_owner_details($propertyid){

    global $connection;

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select * FROM owner WHERE property_id='$propertyid' LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output['owner_id'] = $owner['owner_id'];
        $output['owner_name'] = $owner['owner_name'];
        $output['owner_email'] = $owner['owner_email'];
        $output['owner_mobile'] = $owner['owner_mobile'];
        $output['owner_phone'] = $owner['owner_phone'];
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $output; 

}...
```

Answer (score 2):

I much prefer the idea of a nested `$output` array of `$owner`s indexed by `owner_id`. It is more generic and is less code:

```
 function retrieve_owner_details($propertyid){

    global $connection;

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select * FROM owner WHERE property_id='$propertyid' LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $output=array();
    while($owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[$owner['owner_id']]=$owner;
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $output; 

}...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the "while" for 2 "if" :

```
 function retrieve_owner_details($propertyid){

    global $connection;

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "select * FROM owner WHERE property_id='$propertyid' LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output['owner_id'] = $owner['owner_id'];
        $output['owner_name'] = $owner['owner_name'];
        $output['owner_email'] = $owner['owner_email'];
        $output['owner_mobile'] = $owner['owner_mobile'];
        $output['owner_phone'] = $owner['owner_phone'];
    } 

    if($owner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output['owner_id1'] = $owner['owner_id'];
        $output['owner_name1'] = $owner['owner_name'];
        $output['owner_email1'] = $owner['owner_email'];
        $output['owner_mobile1'] = $owner['owner_mobile'];
        $output['owner_phone1'] = $owner['owner_phone'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $output; 

}...
```